# iOS: How to adjust placement of adjacent UIView based on text in UILabel next to it

Tags: ios, uilabel

[image]

There are two `UIImageView` and two `UILabel` set up like the illustration above. Both `UILabel`'s text will be populated via Web Data and could be any length.

When the `"Something"` label inevitably gets populated with something longer than `"something"`, the `UIImageView` to it's immediate right needs to move to the right based on the amount of text inside the `"something"` label.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: You should use autoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although please use [auto layouts](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1), here is a programmatic way of handling this:

```
// Image before Something text
UIImageView *somethingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 40, 40)];

CGFloat somethingLabelXM = 5.0;
NSString *somethingLabelText = @"Random Text";

CGFloat somethingLabelTextW = [somethingLabelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail].width;

// Something text
UILabel *somethingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(somethingImageView.frame.origin.x + somethingImageView.frame.size.width + somethingLabelXM, somethingImageView.frame.origin.y, somethingLabelTextW, 40.0)];
somethingLabel.text = somethingLabelText;

UIImage *moreImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"];

// Image after Something text
UIImageView *moreImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(somethingLabel.frame.origin.x + somethingLabel.frame.size.width + somethingLabelXM, somethingImageView.frame.origin.y, moreImage.size.width, moreImage.size.height)];
moreImageView.image = moreImage;

// More text
NSString *moreLabelText = @"Random Text";

CGFloat moreLabelTextW = [moreLabelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail].width;

UILabel *moreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(moreImageView.frame.origin.x + moreImageView.frame.size.width + somethingLabelXM, somethingImageView.frame.origin.y, moreLabelTextW, 40.0)];
 somethingLabel.text = moreLabelText;
```